# Parsing PDFs in PDFBOX - extraction order wrong?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, text-extraction

I got to parse (text-extract) a lot of PDF, most of them are "columned" like this (1 page as example):

```
|a|b|c|
|a|b|c|
|a|b|c|
```

My problem is, that some of them are kind of "messed up", so the **display** of those
columns is like the above, but are **text-extracted** in the following order like this:

```
|a|c|b|
|a|c|b|
|a|c|b|
```

What is the approach to get PDFBOX to get the parsing-order right in those cases?

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Why have you tagged this as iText ?

Comment: Cause maybe someone having knowlege with itext knows how to deal with that problem and give an approach to a solution with itext.

Comment: Please supply a sample PDF to inspect. Basically, though, PDFBox sorts very thoroughly during extraction, top to bottom and left to right (unless right-to-left characters are dominant on the page).

Comment: I can't upload a sample file so far due to the contained data, but i'm trying to find a solution to get an example.